# Python Speech Recognition Change Between Microphones

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

By running the following code i get all my available microphone:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

for index, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
    print(f'{index}, {name}')
```

These are all my microphones (and other things) that i have:

```
0, Microsoft Sound Mapper - Input
1, Microphone (Realtek(R) Audio)
2, Stereo Mix (Realtek(R) Audio)
3, Microsoft Sound Mapper - Output
4, Speakers (Realtek(R) Audio)
5, Primary Sound Capture Driver
6, Microphone (Realtek(R) Audio)
7, Stereo Mix (Realtek(R) Audio)
8, Primary Sound Driver
9, Speakers (Realtek(R) Audio)
10, Realtek ASIO
11, Speakers (Realtek(R) Audio)
12, Stereo Mix (Realtek(R) Audio)
13, Microphone (Realtek(R) Audio)
14, Speakers 1 (Realtek HD Audio output with SST)
15, Speakers 2 (Realtek HD Audio output with SST)
16, PC Speaker (Realtek HD Audio output with SST)
17, Microphone 1 (Realtek HD Audio Mic input with SST)
18, Microphone 2 (Realtek HD Audio Mic input with SST)
19, Microphone 3 (Realtek HD Audio Mic input with SST)
20, Stereo Mix (Realtek HD Audio Stereo input)
```

how can I select a specific microphone for speech recognition, I need to swap between the microphone at index 1 and 2 for testing purposes how can I do that.

Code for reference:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Speak Anything!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

    r.energy_threshold = 300
    r.pause_threshold = 1

    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said : {}".format(text))
    except:
        print("Sorry could not recognize what you said!")
```

And is there a way to print the microphone that is currently being used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What device I would select for Speech Recognition to use the audio coming out of my computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57118410/what-device-i-would-select-for-speech-recognition-to-use-the-audio-coming-out-of)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
mic = Microphone(device_index=1)
```

The full code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = Microphone(device_index=1)
with mic as source:
    print("Speak Anything!")
    audio = r.listen(source)
```

Comment: Did you mean 'sr.Microphone(device_index=1)'? I just did 'with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as source:'.